# Loading multiple models and hiding nodes

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I would like load two models and hide some nodes directly after the models are loaded.

I add event listeners to GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT and OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT to see when the loading is finished. Because the loading is done asynchroniously, either one of the models can be loaded last.

So I set the model I want to hide the nodes from active with. And after that hide the nodes I want to hide.

```
viewer.modelstructure.setModel(instanceTree);
```

This works some of the time, but it does not seem to work all the time. Is there some other event I should listen to in order to know the loading is finished? Or is there some way or event to make sure setModel(instanceTree) has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your question about identifying the model which events are fired for ?

In the latest versions of the viewer API, ***viewer.loadModel*** takes a callback that returns the model instance being loaded, this should let you know the model before those 2 other events are fired:

```
Viewer3D.prototype.loadModel = function(url, options, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback, onWorkerStart) {

 // ...

 function onSuccess(model) {
  self.model = model;
  self.impl.addModel(self.model);

  if (self.loadSpinner)
    self.loadSpinner.style.display = "None";

  if (self.model.is2d())
    self.activateLayerState("Initial");

  registerDimensionSpecificHotkeys();

  if (onSuccessCallback) {
    onSuccessCallback(self.model);
  }
 }

 // ...
}
```

And in the event handlers the argument also contain the model instance for which the event is fired:

```
this.viewer.addEventListener(
  Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT, (args) => {
    console.log(args)
  })

this.viewer.addEventListener(
  Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, (args) => {
    console.log(args)
  })
```

[image]

Let me know if I'm missing something and if it doesn't work please provide some code that illustrates your workflow.

Thanks